# Multiarray inputs

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am unable to create a loop to add hours to a multi-array. When I use the method Hours there is an error. I suspect my for-loop is not capturing the input.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Gain 
{
    // Defining array names.
    String[] name = {"A", “B”, “C”, “D”, “E”, “F”, “G”, “H”, “I”, “L”}; 
    int[][] hours = new int[10][3];

    public final int Hours() 
    {
    boolean canceled = false;
    for (int index = 0; index < name.length; index++) {
        JOptionPane.shoeMessageDialog(“Please enter " + name[index] + “’s hours”);
            for (int x = 0; x <= hours.length; x++)
               for (int y = 0; y <= hours[x].length; y++)
        Integer value = promptForInt(artist[index] + “’s first hour: ”);
        if (value != null) {
          while (value < 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please positive figures." + "\nPlease try again.");
            value = promptForInt(name[index] + “’s first hour: ”);
        }
            pay[x][y] = value;
        } else {
            canceled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) // Main program
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= name.length; x++)
           for (int y = 0; y <= hours.length; y++)
              System.out.println(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that your bracketing is causing some issues. As far as I can tell, you don't close your first for loop, I think that you need to use brackets with your second and third loops too.

Comment: Fix your indentantion. Use a debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding in brackets like so:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Gain 
{
    // Defining array names.
    String[] name = {"A", “B”, “C”, “D”, “E”, “F”, “G”, “H”, “I”, “L”}; 
    int[][] hours = new int[10][3];

    public final int Hours() 
    {
        boolean canceled = false;
        for (int index = 0; index < name.length; index++)
        {
            JOptionPane.shoeMessageDialog("Please enter " + name[index] + "’s hours");
            for (int x = 0; x <= hours.length; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y <= hours[x].length; y++)
                {
                    Integer value = promptForInt(artist[index] + “’s first hour: ”);
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        while (value < 0)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please positive figures." + "\nPlease try again.");
                            value = promptForInt(name[index] + “’s first hour: ”);
                        }
                        pay[x][y] = value;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        canceled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) // Main program
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= name.length; x++)
           for (int y = 0; y <= hours.length; y++)
              System.out.println(x, y);
    }
```

While it's fine to avoid brackets in a for loop when you only have one line of code afterwards (like in your `main` method), you need to use them when you have a whole block, as is the case here in your `Hours()` method. Personally, I like to use brackets all of the time as it makes the code more readable, but that's just me. :)